# Should all files in /etc/mysql be owned by root or can mysql own them?

Tags: linux, mysql, file-permissions, permissions

In the standard mysql setup on debian squeeze all files in /etc/mysql are owned by root. Can it be changed, so that mysql is the new owner or does it have a reason why they should stay by root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be changed. The main reason that it's root is because the mysql user doesn't have a shell.
 The user isn't meant to be making changes to the configuration of the service, root or any other group defined by you should . Think of it as a form of privilege separation.

Answer (score 2):

MySQLd runs as root and drops its privileges afterward. Those files are considered sensitive (since it contains your configuration files and such) and should remain as root.

Answer (score 0):

If user `mysql` doesn't need to write to a particular file it doesn't need to own it. Files in /etc/mysql are configuration files which should only be writable by a system administrator e.g. root.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be changed. The main reason that it's root is because the mysql user doesn't have a shell. The user isn't meant to be making changes to the configuration of the service, root or any other group defined by you should . Think of it as a form of privilege separation.